# Is it possible to download the previous version of OneNote for mac

Tags: mac, onenote

I cannot upgrade to Yosemite- company policy- but would still love to use OneNote. Does anyone know a link where I can download the older version? thanks

Comment: Have you checked App Store purchase tab ? If you have Mavericks, then there must be a Mavericks version.

Comment: Thanks you Pratika. I tried your suggestion but it just takes me to the newest version. I'll stop on a Microsoft store later.

Comment: Yes, from the Purchases tab, I can go ahead and download the older version. Thank you..

Answer (score 1):

Now it is possible to download any specific version from the Office 2016 and 2019 suites.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/update-history-office-for-mac